# Congruência vs objetividade dos títulos?

Tags: debate, perguntas, título

Estava aqui a ver a [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/35508/revisions) a esta minha pergunta [Há alguma vantagem em utilizar a função filter_input ao invés de isset?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35508/7210) e dei por mim a pensar, realmente este novo título fica muito melhor (minha opinião).

**Novo:** Há alguma vantagem em utilizar a função filter_input ao invés de isset?

**Antigo:** Obter variável externa isset vs input_filter

Mas entretanto lembro-me que toda a gente que vai pesquisar

> isset vs input_filter

ou até

> Como obter variável externa

Como eu fiz antes de criar a pergunta... Será que um melhor título vale a pena?

É melhor ter um título mais congruente, ou ter um título que faça mais vezes «check» nas pesquisas dos utilizadores? Talvez uma mistura dos dois?

Comment: E se editasse para "Há alguma vantagem em utilizar a função filter_input ao invés de isset para obter variáveis externas?" ou "Há alguma vantagem em utilizar a função filter_input ao invés de isset para receber variáveis de um formulário?" Talvez alguma variante, que mistura os dois.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que o título de chamar atenção para o problema da melhor forma possível. Pesquisa é secundário para ele.

Mas pesquisa é importante. Colocar palavras que ajudam o *post* ser achado é muito bom, só não precisa ser no título.

Acho que depende de cada caso o que escolher para o título. O título pode dar mais força na pesquisa. Idealmente seria bom termos acesso ao que costuma ser pesquisado no site e principalmente nos mecanismos de busca quando acha esta página, mas não temos.

Se acha que é muito importante por no título dá uma editada para acomodar isto. Não vou analisar o caso específico, acho que este debate é mais útil servindo de informação para todos os casos.

Comment: A minha ideia é mesmo discutir isso para todos os casos, este caso foi só que despoletou esta dúvida.